# Magento 2 InvalidArgumentException Could not find a matching version of package

Tags: magento2, extensions, installation, composer

I am trying to install the module using the composer in Magento 2.
I have created a module and publish on the GIT repository and also added the GIT repository URL at packagist.

> Module GIT URL: https://github.com/sumansingh51/suman-hello
>
> Module composer.json:
> https://github.com/sumansingh51/suman-hello/blob/master/composer.json
>
> Module packagist URL:
> https://packagist.org/packages/sumansingh51/suman-hello

Now I am trying to install this module in my Magento project and showing below error

> [root@pt project]# composer require sumansingh51/suman-hello
>
> [InvalidArgumentException]
> Could not find a matching version of package sumansingh51/suman-hello.
> Chec     k the package spelling, your version constraint and that the
> package is ava     ilable in a stability which matches your
> minimum-stability (stable).

Also tried to with `"minimum-stability": "stable"` OR `"minimum-stability": "dev",`

But it showing the same error in terminal.

What things I need to change so I can install the module via `composer`?

How `package` version effect the `composer` installation?